# Upgrading opencart theme journal 2 to journal 3

Tags: opencart, vqmod

I am new to opencart.
I want to upgrade my opencart from journal 2 to journal 3 but I have made some changes in theme files. My first question is:
Will my theme files will be replaced?
I added code for the admin panel using vqmod and in modification. I saved code from modification to original controllers but what about theme files. Is there any way to keep save the theme code and use it in journal 3? I am using opencart version 2.3.x
Thanks

Comment: Journal 2 and journal 3  have completely different architectures. So better completely remove journal2. Even better do not use journla3 at all. This Journal 3 theme completely ruin OC framework by replacing with his own. So all modules which you use, also must be upgraded to support journal3.

Comment: thanks @K.B. . Appreciated